# ISO Date format shows RangeError

Tags: jquery, datepicker, utc, iso

I have to convert a date format to iso format. It works fine but until the date 30. If i use 31/08/2019 it shows range error: Invalid time value at Date.toISOString. Using date picker for this. This error shown for 31 of every month.

```
    function utcDate(element) {
    let val = element.val();
    let split = val.split(/\//);
    var t= split[0]++;
    return new Date([split[1], split[0], split[2]].join('/')).toISOString();
}
```

Comment: It possible that split[0] is the day of month. if today is 31 and you sum is 32 > invalid day?
may you need sum split[1]++ ?

Comment: while using above function without using split[0]++  output shows one date before like if i give start date as 30/08/2019 and end date as 31/08/2019  it shows start date as 29/08/2019 and end date as 30/08/2019. what to do?

Comment: Can you givme an example the element value that you are passing? example: 31/08/2019 ?

Comment: as shown above i have used  30/08/2019  and 31/08/2019  as  start and end date in a form

Comment: Could you tell me whats wrong with the above code and how your code works?

Comment: View here the Date object constructor: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date
And month in javascript first is 0 for january month, and las 11 for december.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it for test mode:

```
                function utcDate(element) {
                    let val = element.val();
                    let split = val.split(/\//);
                    var d = new Date();
                    d.setMonth(parseInt(split[1], 10) - 1);
                    d.setDate(parseInt(split[0], 10));
                    d.setFullYear(parseInt(split[2], 10));
                    return d.toISOString();
                }
```